# How can I sort through JSON?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to sort through some JSON I get from a webpage and set specific attributes of part of the JSON to variables.

Here is some of the code I am using, but I am quite confused and do not work with JSON often.

```
data = json.load(url)
print(list(data['products_and_categories']['Bags']))
```

Here is some of the JSON:

```
{"products_and_categories":{"Bags": [
    {"name":"Duffle Bag","id":172614...},
    {"name":"Backpack","id":172607...}]}
]
```

I want to sort through the JSON based on the name, and then pull the id associated with it.

Comment: You need to be more specific about "set specific attributes of part of the JSON to variables" as well as what you want to use to sort the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
backpackid = null

for x in yourjson['products_and_categories']['Bags']:
    if x['name'] == "Backpack":
        print("found it!")
        backpackid = x['id']

print("Backpack ID is: %", backpackid)
```

Comment: That looks like it should work great, but I get the error, "TypeError: string indices must be integers" Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: That indicates an issue accessing the list: i.e., you are trying to access a property when it is a list and can only be accessed using integer indices.  It's hard to say without seeing the for loop and the exact data you're using.

Comment: Here is the link if that helps https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json  Do I need to do something else with the data other than just loading it?

Comment: The main question is what are you putting in your for loop after the word `in`?  Is it the whole JSON object, just a part of it, or what?

Comment: It's the whole JSON object. Your updated version worked, thanks!

Comment: Great!  When you get a chance mark this as the answer please!